# JFrame with Background Image and JButton using setLocation dont work for me?

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel, imageicon

I wish to add a button on a image in exact locations but everyting in the JPanel dissaper then I use setLayout(null) on the panel.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ImagePanel(String ID)
{
    setLayout(null);
    add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\Train_X2000\\vagn" + ID + ".png")));

    JButton startButton = new JButton("Click Me To Start!");
    startButton.setLayout(null);
    startButton.setLocation(66,66);
    add(startButton);
}
}
```

Does anyone know how this works? I'm really lost here.

/Magnus

Comment: dont use null layout and this is not correct way to add component to null layout.you forget `setBounds()`  ?but i discourage you to do it

Comment: because you've turned the layout manager off, your background is never getting properly sized

Comment: I'd recommend using a JLayeredPane for this. Then you could still use the layout manager for the layers you want laid out

Comment: Thank you I will at JLayeredPane and try to use it instead.